# How to set default Tiles layout in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, tiles

I am developing an sample app which has multiple pages, all pages comes under common layout ( `CommonLayout`: which has `Header`, `Body`, `Footer`).

```xml
<package name="myapp" extends="default" namespace="/">
    <action name="a"><result type="tiles">CommonLayout</result></action>
    <action name="a/create"><result type="tiles">CommonLayout</result></action>
    <action name="b"><result type="tiles">CommonLayout</result></action>
    <action name="b/customize"><result type="tiles">CommonLayout</result></action>
    <action name="b/customize/app"><result type="tiles">CommonLayout</result></action>
    <action name="d/create"><result type="tiles">CommonLayout</result></action>
    <action name="d/view"><result type="tiles">CommonLayout</result></action>
    <action name="d/view/list"><result type="tiles">CommonLayout</result></action>
</package>
```

Every time when I am adding action, I have to duplicate the same line for every action, is there any configuration to mention layout for all actions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use global results per package. For example

```xml
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
  ...
  <global-results>
    <result type="tiles">CommonLayout</result>
  </global-results>
  ...
</package>
<package name="myapp" extends="default" namespace="/">
    <action name="a"/>
    <action name="a/create"/>
    <action name="b"/>
    <action name="b/customize"/>
    <action name="b/customize/app"/>
    <action name="d/create"/>
    <action name="d/view"/>
    <action name="d/view/list"/>
</package>
```